# Magento error : SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'sastadb'@'50.63.196.19' (using password: YES)

Tags: exception, magento-1.7, admin

Unable to view admin page getting error

There has been an error processing your request

SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'sastadb'@'50.63.196.19' (using password: YES)

Trace:

```
#0 /home/content/98/11102498/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/content/98/11102498/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(313): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/content/98/11102498/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /home/content/98/11102498/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /home/content/98/11102498/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/content/98/11102498/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /home/content/98/11102498/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /home/content/98/11102498/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /home/content/98/11102498/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /home/content/98/11102498/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /home/content/98/11102498/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /home/content/98/11102498/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(455): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
#12 /home/content/98/11102498/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(497): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#13 /home/content/98/11102498/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1183): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#14 /home/content/98/11102498/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#15 /home/content/98/11102498/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#16 /home/content/98/11102498/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(413): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#17 /home/content/98/11102498/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#18 /home/content/98/11102498/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /home/content/98/11102498/html/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

Comment: Please provide further details.

Comment: whenever am tryin to login to admin getting this error since i have tried installing region manager extension, website was working fine before that

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing the .xml file related to that extension in app/etc/modules folder. Verify your site now.If you receive same error again, Try by removing the local.xml at the path of app/etc and reinstall magento again with the same database. Check your site now.